# JavaScript if/else Statement assign variable true or false

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

I believe I understand If/else statements using operators and numbers but I am not quite understanding it when it comes to a choice???

For example:
I have two variables, lovesIcecream and typeOfIcecream.
My goal is using an if/else statement, assign lovesIcecream to true if typeofIcecream is 'Chocolate', assign it to false if it is 'Vanilla'. 
This I have so far.

```
if(typeOfIcecream = ???) {
  lovesIcecream = true;
}else {
  lovesIcecream = false;
```

I am not sure where to input 'Chocolate' and 'Vanilla' hence my question marks.
I researched and studied javascript Control flow and if else statements by watching free videos online and it seems that I get the same examples which using numbers such as:

```
if(age >= 16) {
typeOfLicense = ('Full License')
}else {
typeOfLicense = ('None')
}
```

Anyways, If you can help me understand this and maybe suggest what I should be studying exactly to understand the 'typeOfIcecream' code better.

Comment: `if(typeOfIcecream = ???) {` but `=` is assignment, not comparison

Comment: `var lovesIcecream = typeOfIcecream === "chocoloate"` will result in `lovesIcecream` being set to `true` or `false`

Comment: in `age >= 16`, 16 is a constant which decided values of `typeoOfLicense`. Same case you can use in your `Icecream`example. that means instead of `???` you can use constant i.e. `Chocolate`, but as @CertainPerformance said use `===` not an assignment operator

Comment: You should put 'Chocolate' in place of ???. use == in place of =. Read the basics of javascript more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is an assignment operator for comparision you need to use `==` or `===`. You can do it in following ways

```
if(typeOfIcecream == 'Chocalate') {
  lovesIcecream = true;
}else {
  lovesIcecream = false;
```

OR

```
if(typeOfIcecream == 'Chocalate') {
  lovesIcecream = true;
}else if(typeOfIcecream == 'Vanilla'){
  lovesIcecream = false;
```

OR

```
lovesIcecream  = typeOfIcecream == 'Chocolate'? true : false
```

Comment: this is an anti-pattern. `typeOfIcecream == 'Chocolate'` evaluates to `true` or `false` already. There's no need for `if/else` in this case.

Comment: Oh Yes Thanks @user633183. But i just wanted to make him understand how he will gona get into `if` or `else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, i hope this can help you.

EXAMPLE 1

```
var y;
if(y)
console.log(true)
else
console.log(false)
```

> return False;

(When initialize y, start with undefined);

EXAMPLE 2

```
var y = null;
if(y)
console.log(true)
else
console.log(false)
```

> return False;

EXAMPLE 3

```
var y = undefined;
if(y)
console.log(true)
else
console.log(false)
```

> return False;

EXAMPLE 4

```
var y = 0;
if(y)
console.log(true)
else
console.log(false)
```

> return False;

(0, null and undefined, makes the conditional to false);

In another case, if(y) return true;

EXAMPLE 5

```
var y = {}
if(y)
console.log(true)
else
console.log(false)
```

> return true;

EXAMPLE 6

```
var y = function(){};
if(y)
console.log(true)
else
console.log(false)
```

> return true;

in your case, if typeOfIcecream contains a string, you need to compare the two strings.

```
if(typeOfIcecream.localeCompare('chocolate'))
  //typeOfIcecream is not Chocolate
else
  // typeOfIcecream is Chocolate
```

understanding compare..

```
console.log(strB.localeCompare(strA));

/* Expected Returns:

 0 strA == strB

-1 strA < strB (Alfabetic order word)

 1 strA > strB

 */
```